# How to authorize and accept ADB RSA key with broken touch screen on Android

Tags: android, adb

My Nexus 7 2012 has a broken touch screen so I use an OTG mouse with it.  I recently had to do a factory reinstall so am running v5.1 lollipop.  The problem is I now have to re authorize adb with my computer so I can do work on it but cannot accept the RSA key when the dialog pops up because my touch screen is broken.

I cannot use my otg mouse because the Nexus 7 is connected to the computer, I have tried a bluetooth remote android device app which fails to work when the dialog shows, I have tried using another remote android app over wifi, I have tried using my computer keyboard via telnet but fails to work when the dialog appears.  I don't have a bluetooth mouse but don't even know if that would work.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can accept the ADB RSA key dialogue to authorize adb with my computer without the use of a touch screen.  Thanks?

Comment: I think you can get a PC (at least one running Linux) to emulate a bluetooth mouse, so you could see if that will work.  Did the program you found that did not work emulate a keyboard?   Since you just did a factory install anyway, you could a fastboot oem unlock and install a custom recovery with rooted adb and use that to poke around in the main partition.

Comment: Yes anything bluetooth or wireless I tried did work on the tablet but as soon as the dialog pops up it no longer works so I couldn't click it - probably for security.  I have just rooted the device again.  I don't really want to do a custom ROM.  There is away to do the keys manually like aorlando said but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using macOS (or any Linux distro):

1. Reboot your phone into recovery mode.
2. Connect it to your computer.
3. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
    cd ~/.android
    adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
   ```
4. All done! Just `adb shell reboot` and feel the power!

*For Windows 10, .android directory is located in your the base of your C:\User\user_name directory.

Comment: This also works for Ubuntu/Arch Linux

Comment: it doesn't work for me!

error: failed to get feature set: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

I think they doesn't think that user could try to enable it with broken screen

Comment: Didn't work for me either - same error message as Daniel Jose Padilla Pena.

Comment: `adb push` does not work if debug grant popup is not accepted!

Comment: @JRichardsz wonder if this is a recent change with a newer Android version? Certainly worked for me 4 years ago when I needed it. 

Comment: How do you reboot into recovery mode without seeing the screen?

Comment: "without seeing the screen" hmm.. this is the answer I seek. Maybe by sheer luck! But being an android dev, I have lost hopes since grant popup is security before you can access a device.

Answer (score 5):

Using OTG and teamviewer help me control a broken touch screen android.

Comment: how do you install it on broken device?

Comment: @DanielJosePadillaPeña, I know this is old, but in case some else needs it: You can install software from https://play.google.com/ to your device, as long as You're logged-in on the browser and have that account linked to your device.

Comment: @Skaparate. OK, I was able to install it (at least Play Store says so). How do I access it from a PC?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski you need to install teamviewer on your computer and link both devices to the same account, which should enable you to remote control the phone. If you have never installed teamviewer before on your phone, then it will not work, as You would need to login to teamviewer on the phone. Your best bet in this case might be to buy a HDMI adapter to connect the phone to a screen.

Answer (score 2):

If screen is broken and you can't enable ADB by clicking on a confirmation dialog with the RSA key, you can run TWRP Recovery and copy a file from this mode:

```
adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/
```

But it will work only on a rooted device.

Comment: To clearify; adb push <path to new adb_keys file> /data/misc/adb/

Adding adb_keys to the target path would put it in a folder called adb_keys which isn't right.

Comment: did not work for me on android 11.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the RSA key copying it from computer and adding the line to /data/misc/adb/adb_keys, but only with rooted device

Comment: Thanks is there anyway to do it without rooting the device

Comment: is it broken the display or the touch? you can watch what happens on the screen?

Comment: the display is fine, the digitizer is gone so touch doesn't work.  I have just rooted it there and am going to attempt to do it manually like you suggested.

Comment: if you have a microusb -> usb adapter you can use a mouse ;)

Comment: I can't do that because I need the nexus 7 connected to the computer to connect to adb

Comment: Aorlando how would I do what you suggest?  I can find the adb key on the computer in .android/adbkey but don't see /data/misc/adb/adb_keys?

Comment: You may need to look through platform/system/core/adb in the AOSP sources to see if this has moved, if it doesn't exist until there are entries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple (although a little bit late..). You can download the teamviewer host from the playstore and teamviewer into your phone from your computer. Once the adb authorization prompt appears just accept it through teamviewer and you are set. Remember to check "Remember this computer" so you don't have to do this every time. Keep in mind that to control your device through teamviewer you need to add it to an account.

Comment: OK, I've installed the teamviewer via Play Store website. Now what? How do I connect to it?

Comment: the question says broken touch screen. so how can we install teamviewer on the phone

Comment: You can install it from any other device via the web version of Play Store by logging in to the same Google account that your phone is using. Just click install and choose your device.