# How do I enable USB debugging from TWRP recovery?

Tags: android, adb, recovery, usb-debugging

I have a android device with dead screen. I have installed TWRP recovery for adb interactions while in recovery. I have lineage os 16.0 (Android 9) on my device. I want to access the device screen via using scrcpy. But I don't have developer mode enabled meaning USB debugging is not enabled.

How do I enable USB debugging while in TWRP recovery?

Host device will be windows PC with ADB installed.

I have seen some online guide as in how to push RSA key. from [How to authorize and accept ADB RSA key with broken touch screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178911/how-to-authorize-and-accept-adb-rsa-key-with-broken-touch-screen-on-android). It says I should use

```
cd ~/.android` then `adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
```

Is this still applied in Android 9 or lineage os 16.0? Since this guide is little dated.

Note: I search for similar topic and all the answers are about how to back up the phone not how to enable USB debugging. This is not what I want. All I want to know is how to enable USB debugging through editing files while in recovery adb.